# Linking Types in Scala

Tags: scala, dependent-type

I have a class of objects which either have one type of ID or another:

```
sealed trait ItemId
case class NumericId(id: Int) extends ItemId
case class StringId(id: String) extends ItemId

sealed trait Item {
  def id: ItemId
}

case class ItemWithNumericId(id: NumericId) extends Item
case class ItemWithStringId(id: StringId) extends Item
```

I'd like to create an interface for some sort of service which retrieves items:

```
trait ItemService[IdType <: ItemId, ItemType <: Item] {
  def get(id: IdType): ItemType
}
```

How do I link the `ItemId` type with the `Item` type to put a constraint on `ItemService`s to not allow something like:

```
class SillyItemService extends ItemService[NumericId, ItemWithStringId] {
  def get(id: NumericId): ItemWithStringId = ???
}
```

---

I've realised I can add generic types to the `Item` class:

```
sealed trait ItemId
case class NumericId(id: Int) extends ItemId
case class StringId(id: String) extends ItemId

sealed trait Item[Id <: ItemId] {
  def id: Id
}

case class ItemWithNumericId(id: NumericId) extends Item[NumericId]
case class ItemWithStringId(id: StringId) extends Item[StringId]

trait ItemService[IdType <: ItemId, ItemType <: Item[IdType]] {
  def get(id: IdType): ItemType
}
```

which is OK but It's super verbose. Ideally, the service would only have a single generic type.

Thanks very much for any answers/input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
 trait Item {
    type IdType
    def id: IdType
 }

 trait ItemService[I <: Item] {
   def get(id: I#IdType): Item
 }
```

Comment: This is really nice. The implementations of the `ItemService` have the constraints I wanted and they can be declared with minimal boilerplate code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This would be my approach:

```
sealed trait ItemId
case class NumericId(id: Int) extends ItemId
case class StringId(id: String) extends ItemId

trait Item[A <: ItemId] {
  def id: A
}

trait ItemService[A <: ItemId, B <: Item[A]] {
  def get(id: A): B
}
```

It's honestly not much different from what you had done, I just think there's not much need to make the `Item` trait sealed and introduce two implementations right there.

If you have no use for narrowing the return type of the `get` method of a specific `ItemService`, you could even leave off the `B` type parameter to make things one step simpler:

```
trait ItemService[A <: ItemId] {
  def get(id: A): Item[A]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Path dependant types are one option which is covered by the other answer, but for the purposes of flexibility I would personally go with implicits/context bounds in this case.

```
trait Proof[IdType <: ItemId, ItemType <: Item[IdType]]

trait ItemService[IdType <: ItemId, ItemType <: Item[IdType]] {
  def get(id: IdType)(implicit ev: Proof[IdType, ItemType])
}
```

You can also make `trait` an `abstract class` to hoist the declaration of the implicit proof, or whatever other party trick from the many available lets you sidestep the need to include the evidence on every method on the service.

Then I'd make a companion object for `Proof` and list the correlations feasible within your domain.

```
object Proof {
  implicit numericProof: Proof[NumericId, ItemWithNumericId] = new Proof[NumericId, ItemWithNumericId] {}
  ...
}
```

At this point you don't really care what your service looks like, though f bounded polymorphism may later allow you for super fine grained control, as you can specialise implicits for specific implementations as well as create ambiguous proofs where you want to give compile time errors for things that aren't meant to be mixed together.